# Twitter Bootstrap и картинки

Tags: bootstrap, изображения, адаптивная-верстка

На `lg` и `md` все нормально, а на `sm` сетка ломается.
У картинок 100% ширины, высота авто. Может, кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

P.S. Реальные размеры изображений отличаются на 1pх или в ширину, или в высоту:  175х100, 175х101, 176х100.

http://joxi.ru/Y2L4XEvCKOzP26

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить картинкам `display: block` - они перестанут иметь снизу зазор в 1 пиксель, как это делают строчные элементы

Comment: (http://joxi.ru/l2ZMNQpupOdOmJ)
пробовал, не помогает) всю башку сломал.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можете поставить после каждой пары:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
```